# Can massive damage kill you while at 0 HP?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, character-death, hit-points

The rules on ["Instant Death"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#InstantDeath) state:

> Massive damage can kill you instantly. When damage **reduces you to 0 hit points** and there is damage remaining, you die if the remaining damage equals or exceeds your hit point maximum [...]

Does this *only* apply if you aren't already at 0 HP? Or rather, what happens if you are currently at 0 HP and take massive damage?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

## Yes, Massive Damage can kill you at 0 HP

> Damage at 0 Hit Points. If you take any damage while you have 0 hit points, you suffer a death saving throw failure. If the damage is from a critical hit, you suffer two failures instead. **If the damage equals or exceeds your hit point maximum, you suffer instant death.**
>
> —**Death Saving Throws**, Player's Handbook, pg. 197

Mathematically, this is equivalent to the normal rule that occurs when a character is above 0 hit points, so it makes perfect sense that they would reimplement the rule here in precisely this manner.